# Eclipse find and replace value within quotation marks

Tags: eclipse

I have multiple strings like this;

```
"INNER JOIN ms.sector sec "
```

what I want to do is find an exact word within this strings and replace it with another, but only if this word is within quotation marks. e.g:

change sector to territory so the above string will be:

```
"INNER JOIN ms.territory sec "
```

Can you help me find a suitable regex to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this out

1. List item
2. CTRL-F
3. Check the Check Box for "Regular Expressions"
4. In Find put:  "(.*)sector(.*)"
5. In Replace with put: "$1territory$2"

As per your examples, when the above was run it did not alter this:

`String sector;`

But did change both of these:

`String test1 = "INNER JOIN ms.sector sec ";`

`String test21 = "OUTER JOIN ms.sector sec ";`

To:

`String test1 = "INNER JOIN ms.territory sec ";`

`String test21 = "OUTER JOIN ms.territory sec ";`

There may be a more elegant way, but this is using Reg-Ex capture groups, e.g. [refcapture](https://www.regular-expressions.info/refcapture.html)

Comment: And thanks for making me search for and try that out as I've needed to do it in the past and never took the time to make it work until now ;-)

Comment: Did this help Rena?

Comment: it did not work, I am using this regex to do the search: `\".*sector.*\"`, but when using the above patter to replace it changes the whole line.

Comment: nvm I was able to do it with this for the search: `\"(.*)tbAccionCita(.*)\"`, I am  marking this as answer since it helped me with the replace.

Comment: Glad I could help out Rena!